# NASM: "comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand" when declaring a string

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to use NASM to make an assembly code program, but for some reason it keeps giving me an error. It says it expects a comma, colon, decorator, or end of line after I declare a string, but I don't see how it can be an issue Please advise.

```
section .text
        global main
main:
        mov edi,str
lab3:
        cmp [edi],' '
        je lab1

        cmp [edi],0x0
        je lab2

        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,edi
        mov edx,1
        int 0x80
        inc edi
        jmp lab3
lab1:
        inc edi
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,nwln
        mov edx,1
        int 0x80
        jmp lab3

lab2:
        mov eax,1
        int 0x80

section .data
str db 'this is a test',0x0     ;this is the line giving the error
nwln db 0xa
```

Comment: nasm requires colons after labels, i.e. `str: db 'this is a test',0x0`

Comment: @Jester: no it doesn't, only when they're also valid mnemonics :P  That's why the `-Worphan-labels` option exists.  The OP's program assembles when changing `str` to `str1`.  (Except of course for the missing operand-sizes on the `cmp mem, immediate` instructions)

Comment: Better to always use it, one less headache. Also, what happens if next year intel introduces a new instruction that collides with your label name...

Comment: @Jester: Totally agree that it fixes the problem and is a good idea for style / future-proofing, just not from a language-rules perspective.  Will update my answer to suggest it.

Answer (score 6):

[STR](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/STR.html) (Store Task Register) is an instruction mnemonic.  You're using it as a label without a colon.  `str: db ...` would have worked.

YASM gives a more useful error message here: `string.asm:33: error: unexpected DB/DW/etc. after instruction`

---

It's good practice to **always use a `:` after a label name**, whether you're labelling code or data.  It's clearer for human readers, and more future-proof against future instruction mnemonics or assembler directives.

It's also a good idea to **build with [`-Worphan-labels`](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html)** so you get a warning if you write something like `cqde` (not `cqde:`) on a line by itself.  Without that option, it puts a label at that line.  With that option, you'll get a warning and notice that you typoed `cdqe`!  (Or any other no-operand x86 instructions.)

---

BTW, don't forget to use `cmp byte [edi],' '` operand-size modifiers when using instructions with an immediate and a memory operand, because it won't assemble with an ambiguous operand-size.

Also, use meaningful label-names.  Like `.space_found` instead of `lab1`.