# NASM - printf doesn't print the first character

Tags: assembly, printf, nasm, x86-64

I want to write a program which returns the string you write. But it always prints it without the first character. Also, it doesn't return anything past the first space.

Example:

```
IN: test
OUT: est
```

Code:

```
extern printf, scanf, exit
global main

section .text
main:
    push rbp
                            ;input of string
    mov rdi, format
    mov rsi, string
    mov rax, 0
    call scanf

                            ;output of string
    mov rdi, format_out
    mov rsi, qword [string]
    mov rax, 0
    call printf
_exit:                        ;end of program
    pop rbp
    call exit

section .data
  format     db "%s", 0
  string     db 0
  format_out db "You wrote: %s", 0
```

I noticed that if I change `string db 0` to `string db`", it shows an error, but the program works correctly, printing the entire sentence to the first space. Unfortunately I don't have any clue what to do with that info. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I guess `string` is the variable where you store the string entered by the user. How many chars do you expect the user to enter? What is the size of variable `string`?

Comment: Well I don't know. Let''s say that 20 is the max number of characters. What do I do now?

Comment: Then you should allocate more than 1 byte for the string, enough for your 20 max

Comment: I don't know this syntax but why do `mov rsi, string` and `mov rsi, qword [string]` look different? The calls should be the same.

Comment: Well I tried 'string dd 0' but this isn't the way to go :/

Comment: Zumalo, your string is too small, it's one byte. You need something like `string times 21 db 0`.

Comment: Why with the exact same code I now get Segmentation fault?

Comment: Restart computer and try again.

Comment: I restarted, but it's still the same.
"Segmentatnion fault (core dumped)"

Comment: Check first part of this answer (does apply to 32b too): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575898/how-to-use-strings-in-emu8086/40580889#40580889  .. Also you didn't even notice that not only it does print it without first character, but the `"You wrote: "` is completely missing :) (as it's overwritten by the user input). If you would put this into debugger, you would see the `format_out` string is damaged (upon memory inspection just ahead of `printf` call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("%s", ...)` takes a pointer arg, but you're passing it the first 8 bytes of the contents of your string.  Use `mov rsi, string` to get a mov-immediate instead of `mov rsi, [string]` (which is a load).

(Or to save 2 code bytes, `mov esi, string` since static addresses are guaranteed to fit in 32 bits in the default code model.)

---

As pointed out in comments, your static buffer is too small.  Since your format string has no size limit, you need an infinite-size buffer to avoid any risk of a long input line overflowing it.

But let's pretend that a 1024B buffer is safe enough.  Or better, use `%1023s` so it is guaranteed to be enough.  We don't want 1024B of zeros in our executable; that would be silly.  So we should instead reserve 1024B in the BSS:

```
section .rodata
  format:     db "%1023s", 0         # actually set a size limit, leaving room for the \0
  format_out: db "You wrote: %s", 0

section .bss
  string:     resb 1024              # RESERVE 1024 bytes.  Only works in .bss
```

There's no reason to omit the `:` after label names on data, and [good reason not to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40559438/nasm-comma-colon-decorator-or-end-of-line-expected-after-operand-when-decla/40559480#40559480).