# Why doesn't NASM have trouble with valid instruction mnemonics as symbol names in operands?

Tags: parsing, assembly, compiler-construction, x86, nasm

I wrote the following simple program, but nasm refuses to compile it.

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 0x01 
    mov rdi, 0x01
    mov rsi, str
    mov rdx, 0x03
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    syscall

segment .data
    str db 'Some string'


nasm -f elf64 main.asm
main.asm:15: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
```

As I read in this [***answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40559480/2786156) this is because `str` is an instruction mnemonic. So I added a colon to `str` and now it compiles fine. But what about the line

```
mov rsi, str
```

**`str` is an instruction mnemonic here, but it still compiles fine. Why?**

Comment: nasm is treating 'str' obviously as a label, and thus doesn't complain. "std db 'some string' " is a syntax error, this is found in step1 already, way before someone tries to resolve the "str" label

Comment: Oops, sorry, you're asking *why* it doesn't compile.  Not a duplicate.  Was probably your upvote that brought that old answer to my attention before I looked at this :P

Comment: you can even use "`mov rsi, mov`" and "`mov: db 'something'`" and nasm will not complain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the NASM manual explains](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html), other than macro definitions and directives, the format of a NASM source line has some combination of these four fields:

```
label:    instruction operands        ; comment
```

After it sees `mov` as the mnemonic, it's no longer considering the remaining tokens as possible instruction mnemonics.  Assembly language is strictly one instruction per statement.

**If you wanted the bytes that encode an `str ax` instruction as the immediate operand for `mov`-sign-extended-imm32, you'd have to do that yourself with a numeric constant.**  NASM syntax doesn't have a way to do that for you, so its parser doesn't need to recurse into the operands once its found a mnemonic.

---

Or instead of encoding `str` manually, use a `db` to emit the bytes of the `mov` instruction.

```
db 0x48, 0xc7, 0xc6    ; REX.W prefix, opcode for mov r/m64,imm32,  ModR/M = rsi destination
      str  [rax+1]     ; a disp8 makes this 4 bytes long.


;; same machine code as
mov rsi, strict dword 0x0148000f    ; str [rax+1]

;; nasm optimizes it to mov esi, imm32 without strict dword.
;; I guess I should have used that 5-byte instruction for the DB version...
```